# Remove "p" tag from content generated by a WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I realize there are dozens of this *type* of question, but since I can't find in any of them the solution to this specific problem, it's unlikely a "This question has already been answered here" type addition will make much sense. And to anyone who's ever tried getting a real, specific, detailed answer on the WordPress.org forums, good luck!

I'm using the Store Locator Plus plugin. Had some back-end coding issues which I had to fix because getting the guy (or company) who wrote it to answer questions on his website forum is like pulling teeth (not that anybody who spends $300 on a plugin deserves support, but anyhoo...)

So, here is a chunk of code where I hard coded a submit button html. Then I worked with a custom style sheet, and the button actually does work and look nice. The problem is that on the html source, WordPress has sprinkled spurious `<p>` and `</p>` tags in the html I created.

For now, please don't dwell on how the button is made, which is a bit of a hack. There are reasons why I used a div tag within a button content, it's because without it the text in the straight button comes out really crappy, not vertically aligned correctly, can't control the font-family or font-size values. Those problems will be for another question, at another time.

Here is the function in the plugin where I created a custom button:

```
    function create_DefaultSearchDiv_Submit() {

    $this->slplus->debugMP('msg',__FUNCTION__);
    if (get_option(SLPLUS_PREFIX.'_disable_search') == 0) {

        // Find Button Is An Image
        //
        if ($this->slplus->settings->get_item('disable_find_image','0','_') === '0') {
            $sl_theme_base=SLPLUS_UPLOADURL."/images";
            $sl_theme_path=SLPLUS_UPLOADDIR."/images";

            if (!file_exists($sl_theme_path."/search_button.png")) {
                $sl_theme_base=SLPLUS_PLUGINURL."/images";
                $sl_theme_path=SLPLUS_PLUGINDIR."/images";
            }

            $sub_img=$sl_theme_base."/search_button.png";
            $mousedown=(file_exists($sl_theme_path."/search_button_down.png"))?
                "onmousedown=\"this.src='$sl_theme_base/search_button_down.png'\" onmouseup=\"this.src='$sl_theme_base/search_button.png'\"" :
                "";
            $mouseover=(file_exists($sl_theme_path."/search_button_over.png"))?
                "onmouseover=\"this.src='$sl_theme_base/search_button_over.png'\" onmouseout=\"this.src='$sl_theme_base/search_button.png'\"" :
                "";
            $button_style=(file_exists($sl_theme_path."/search_button.png"))?
                "type='image' class='slp_ui_image_button' src='$sub_img' $mousedown $mouseover" :
                "type='submit'  class='slp_ui_button'";

        // Find Button Image Is Disabled
        //
        } else {
            $button_style = 'type="submit" class="slp_ui_button"';
        }

        // TODO: find_button_label get_option should move to Enhanced Search

            $string = "<div id='radius_in_submit'><button type=\"submit\" id=\"addressSubmit\" class=\"slp_ui_button\"><div class=\"button-inner\" >Find A Store</div></button></div>";

            return $string;
    }

    return '';
}
```

You can see that two or three lines from the bottom, just before the closing bracket of the function, I wrote a variable named `$string` with the string value being the html of the button, which is wrapped in a div with an id='radius_in_submit'.

Now, here is the html output of the button:

```
<div id='radius_in_submit'><button type="submit" id="addressSubmit" class="slp_ui_button"></p>
<div class="button-inner" >Find A Store</div>
<p></button></div>
</p>
</div>
```

You can see that the "p" tags totally don't belong there.

What have I tried...I have tried many variations on adding the remove_filter('the_content','wpautop'); in the theme's functions.php file, but that has never really worked for me on anything for some reason.

Here is the latest code I tried, inserted just before the closing ?> in my functions.php file:

```
function rm_wpautop($content) {
   global $post;
   // Remove the filter
   remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
   return $content;
}

// Hook into the Plugin API
add_filter('the_content', 'rm_wpautop', 9);
```

...but it doesn't solve my problem. The button does work, I could leave it alone, but I can't stand those p tag insertions.

Development url where you can see it: [store locator](http://tecinfrared.com/store-locator/)

Comment: have you resaved the post since you inserted the code? actually you dont need to insert the remove_filter in a filter, you can just insert it into your functions file.

Comment: I hear you say "don't dwell..." but still I wonder, can't you use '<span>' instead of '<div>' (and perhaps change the display with CSS)?

Comment: @ ECO13 I tried span. Didn't work. For some reason, I don't know if there is some other stylesheet somewhere overriding my styles, but span didn't let me specify font-size, font-family, padding, or anything that let me position or modify the text and font. But the div tag did let me modify the font & position.

Comment: @David I guess I don't know what you mean by "post". I'm not posting anything, in the sense of a blog post. I don't think this is going through the TinyMCE, but maybe I don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: sorry i assumed you were using shortcodes to insert the button...the_content filter only runs on the content saved in posts or pages, wp does not touch code on templates. looking at your function there, there is only 1 line of code that is relevant `$string = "<div id='radius_in_submit'><button type=\"submit\";` try rewriting it to `$string = '<div id="radius_in_submit"><button type="submit" ';`  (complete the rest of the line). Also try creating a static vers and save as a page template, remove the refs to js/jquery one by one, you might have js doing some rendering for you?

Comment: Thanks @David. I'll keep trying. I have a lot to learn about WordPress methodology.